# Use of ResolveUnregisteredType causes Torn Lifestyle warning in Simple Injector v3.0.3

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I use a self-made "external" library to get some basic infrastructure in place when creating new web-applications. I recently made some changes to how my repositories work and came across this warning from Simple Injector Diagnostic Warnings:

> SimpleInjector.DiagnosticVerificationException : The configuration is
>   invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
>   -[Torn Lifestyle] The registration for IUnitOfWork maps to the same implementation and lifestyle as the registrations for IUnitOfWork,
>   IUnitOfWork, IUnitOfWork and IUnitOfWork do. They all map to
>   EmptyUnitOfWork (Singleton). This will cause each registration to
>   resolve to a different instance: each registration will have its own
>   instance. See the Error property for detailed information about the
>   warnings. Please see https://simpleinjector.org/diagnostics how to fix
>   problems and how to suppress individual warnings.

The core assembly of my library has an empty implementation of `IUnitOfWork` called `EmptyUnitOfWork` which is just a simple no-op class:

```
internal sealed class EmptyUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

This class is then registered in the container when there is no other unit of work avaliable. I do this by using the `container.ResolveUnregisteredType(...)` like so:

```
// Register an EmptyUnitOfWork to be returned when a IUnitOfWork is requested:
container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.UnregisteredServiceType == typeof(IUnitOfWork))
    {
        // Register the instance as singleton.
        var registration = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<IUnitOfWork, EmptyUnitOfWork>(container);
        e.Register(registration);
    }
};
```

First time I've used above method - but works fine with this test:

```
[Fact]
public void RegistersEmptyUnitOfWork_AsSingleton_WhenIUnitOfWorkIsNotRegisted()
{
    var instance = _container.GetInstance<IUnitOfWork>();
    var registration = _container.GetRegistration(typeof (IUnitOfWork));

    Assert.NotNull(instance);
    Assert.IsType<EmptyUnitOfWork>(instance);
    Assert.Equal(Lifestyle.Singleton, registration.Lifestyle);
}
```

Now for the fun part, I have an extension method in a supporting library which registers an EntityFramework `IUnitOfWork` if my application needs one:

```
public static void RegisterEntityFramework<TContext>(this Container container) where TContext : DbContext
{
    if (container == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(container));

    var lifestyle = Lifestyle.CreateHybrid(() =>
        HttpContext.Current != null,
        new WebRequestLifestyle(),
        new LifetimeScopeLifestyle()
    );

    container.Register<DbContext, TContext>(lifestyle);
    container.Register<IUnitOfWork, EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork>(lifestyle);
    container.Register(typeof (IRepository<>), typeof (EntityFrameworkRepository<>), lifestyle);
}
```

But somehow this throws the warning from Simple Injector - but I just injected the `EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork` so the `EmptyUnitOfWork` should not be triggered?

The reason for this design is that I have a `CommandTransactionDecorator` in my core library which uses the `IUnitOfWork` to save changes. I just want to have an empty one if a `IUnitOfWork` is not required by the application.

For reference this is the decorator:

```
 internal sealed class CommandTransactionDecorator<TCommand> : IHandleCommand<TCommand> where TCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly Func<IHandleCommand<TCommand>> _handlerFactory;

    public CommandTransactionDecorator(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, Func<IHandleCommand<TCommand>> handlerFactory)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _handlerFactory = handlerFactory;
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command)
    {
        _handlerFactory().Handle(command);
        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

It seems like this is the registration that makes the warning:

```
var registration = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<IUnitOfWork, EmptyUnitOfWork>(container);
e.Register(registration);
```

Changing it to `e.Register(() => new EmptyUnitOfWork());` makes the warning go away, but then the lifestyle is not singleton?

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me why you are seeing this warning and I'm not able to reproduce it. Could you post an example on Github that reproduces the problem? Perhaps it is a bug.

Comment: I'll set one up, hold on..

Comment: @Steven: https://github.com/janhartmann/simpleinjector-verify-warning

Comment: @Steven: (Meta:) Your request to the OP to post code on an external site strikes me as somewhat unusual. IMHO code that is relevant to the question should be posted *here*, as part of the question (if feasible) -- questions seeking debugging help are expected to include a minimally complete code example, after all.

Comment: @stakx: If it is a bug, I like to have it reported on Simple Injector's project site https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector. Stackoverflow is for questions, not for bug reports. What I was hoping for was to see a new issue with a unit test to reproduce. Unfortunately OP posted a whole project. This means I didn't make myself clear enough what I was expecting from him.

Comment: I am sorry, I'll create the unit test and post it here.

Comment: @janhartmann: This bug is fixed in patch release v3.0.4.

Comment: Great, thanks for this @Steven :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is that `ResolveUnregisteredType` is called multiple times. This causes multiple singleton registrations for the same type to be made. Each registration gets its own instance. This will result in an application that consists of multiple instances of that type, which is usually not what you want to happen when you register a type as singleton. Since your `EmptyUnitOfWork` doesn't have any behavior, there is probably no problem, but Simple Injector can obviously not guess that this is the case, so it throws an exception.

What you are experiencing however is a breaking change / bug that was introduced in Simple Injector v3. In Simple Injector v1 and v2 the resulting registration of a `ResolveUnregisteredType` was cached; which meant that a call to `Verify()` would trigger your custom delegate just once. In Simple Injector v3.0 however, the resulting registration isn't cached anymore. This was an oversight, that has slipped through. The idea was to make `ResolveUnregisteredType` context aware. To be context aware, caching was not an option anymore. So caching was removed, but we eventually decided not to make `ResolveUnregisteredType` context aware, while we forgot to add the caching again.

The funny thing of this accidental behavior however is, that it expose a bug in your code. This bug already existed even when you used v2, but v3 now (accidentally) slaps you in the face with it. With v2, the correctness of your registration depended on the use of the `Verify()` method. `Verify()` builds all object graphs on a single thread. Without the use of `Verify()` however, the object graphs are compiled lazily and in case you are running a multi-threaded application, multiple threads can simultaneously call `ResolveUnregisteredType`; Simple Injector never locked `ResolveUnregisteredType` and this is documented.

So the result of this is that without a call to `Verify()` you could still end up in multiple registrations of that specific component, which of course again could lead to really ugly hard to find problems, that usually only appear once in a way in production.

This is how you should actually write that registration:

```
Lazy<Registration> registration = new Lazy<Registration>(() =>
    Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration<IUnitOfWork, EmptyUnitOfWork>(container));

container.ResolveUnregisteredType += (sender, e) => {
    if (e.UnregisteredServiceType == typeof(IUnitOfWork)) {
        e.Register(registration.Value);
    }
};
```

With Simple Injector v3 however, you hardly ever have to use the `ResolveUnregisteredType` event anymore. You can do make the following registration instead:

```
container.RegisterConditional<IUnitOfWork, EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Scoped,
    c => true);

// NOTE: This registration must be made second
container.RegisterConditional<IUnitOfWork, EmptyUnitOfWork>(Lifestyle.Singleton, 
    c => !c.Handled);
```

This solves the problem of having to think about multi-threading completely. Here we make two conditional registrations, where the first is always applied (using the predicate `c => true`). You might be tempted to make the first registration unconditional using `Register<IUnitOfWork, EFUoW>()`, but that won't work, because Simple Injector will detect that the second registration can never be applied and an exception will be thrown. So the use of the `c => true` predicate suppresses this detection. I wouldn't usually advice such construct, because it blinds Simple Injector. In your case however it seems reasonable, because both registrations are made at different moment.

I now will have to think about whether or not I want to change this behavior in v3 and do caching. Advantage of caching is that it can improve performance, but the downside is that it hides bugs.

Comment: Thanks you Steven, I really appreciate your in-dept answers. Greatly written and easy to understand. I'll go with the first solution for now, since I do not have access to the `EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork` in the registration right there (lives in another assembly). I have to figure out how to re-structure the application for the `RegisterConditional(...)` solution afterwards as I like that one better.

Comment: Found a way to use `RegisterConditional(...)` in my application. Great! :-)